# bound and frame for a UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I just want to easily print out myButton dimensions. please check the code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

and .m file:

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize myButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CGRect f2 = self.myButton.bounds;
    printf("x: %f\n", f2.origin.x);


    CGSize f3 = self.myButton.frame.size;
    printf("x: %f\n", f3.height);
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    CGRect f2 = self.myButton.bounds;
    printf("x: %f\n", f2.origin.x);


    CGSize f3 = self.myButton.bounds.size;
    printf("x: %f\n", f3.height);
}
```

This is what I received in the console:

```
x: 0.000000
x: 0.000000
x: 0.000000
x: 0.000000
```

Can you help me how can I print them?

[image]

Comment: are u positive that you have connected the IBOutlet to a UIButton in xib

Comment: try this NSLog(@"Button Frame -- %@",[myButton description]); In this check your frame (or) NSLog(@"Button Frame -- %@",[myButton.frame]);

Comment: this is what I received : `2012-10-09 12:16:23.470 test[2081:c07] Button Frame -- <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x7176bd0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7176ca0>>`

Comment: why aren't you using NSLog() instead of printf()?

Answer (score 3):

in case of autolayouts it continues calculating the frame till the `viewWillAppear` is called, posting the `NSLog` in `viewDidAppear` method will give you the result your desired bounds of button

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
myButton.frame.origin.x;
myButton.frame.origin.y;
myButton.frame.size.width;
myButton.frame.size.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pleas check, have reference the outlet in .xib or Storyboard (whatever you are using).

Comment: I did, I am pretty sure. even I created a new project and tested it again.

Comment: just use frame instead of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code for your viewDidLoad :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect f2 = self.myButton.frame;
    NSLog("x origin: %f\n", f2.origin.x);
    NSLog("y origin: %f\n", f2.origin.y);
    NSLog("height: %f\n", f2.size.height);
    NSLog("width: %f\n", f2.size.width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also something to be aware of is that you can use the convenience methods:

```
NSLog(@"self.myButton.bounds = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.myButton.bounds));
NSLog(@"self.myButton.frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.myButton.frame));
```

To quickly and easily print out a CGRect without having to use a load of different string formats or NSLog statements

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for the record, the dimensions of your button will *not* be set in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear. Use **viewDidLayoutSubviews** when using auto layout. This is an important gotcha. Also, this may be called numerous times. So, if you're doing something expensive with the values, handle it.