# UIButton - Frame and Bounds Zero - Page Based Application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard

There is a similar but unresolved question
[bound and frame for a UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797477/bound-and-frame-for-a-uibutton)

I am using Storyboards with autolayout and The "**Page Based Application Template**"

I am able to reproduce this problem by making the standard page based application adding a button to the storyboard and referencing it in

**viewDidAppear** of the DataViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"View did appear");
    NSLog(@"self.myButton.bounds = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.myButton.bounds));
    NSLog(@"self.myButton.frame = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.myButton.frame));
    NSLog(@"self.myButton = %@",self.myButton);
}
```

**output**
2013-05-14 19:37:45.954 FrameTest4[10777:c07] View did appear
2013-05-14 19:37:45.966 FrameTest4[10777:c07] self.myButton.bounds = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
2013-05-14 19:37:45.968 FrameTest4[10777:c07] self.myButton.frame = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
2013-05-14 19:37:45.970 FrameTest4[10777:c07] self.myButton = >

**The header file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    
@interface DataViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dataLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id dataObject;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

When I run the same code with a single view application also with **autolayout** and storyboards it works fine.

The reason I need this information is I need to run an animation which ends at the button. 
Thanks
Ryan

Comment: Not clear from your log: is your button nil?

Comment: The button is not nil just the frame and bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this kind of thing in the new iOS 5 method `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Be careful though, as this method is potentially called more than just once, so yo might have to keep a flag around to track this.

Comment: Thanks - I did try that method but it also did not work. I have a feeling I may have to use contraints

Comment: I did try that yesterday and it did not work and tried it again today and now it seems to have a value. Answer accepted thank you.